# Certbot DNS challenge with Dnsimple plugin

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot, dnsimple

How can I use Certbot's Dnsimple plugin to acquire and renew automatically a certificate with DNS challenge? I can't find any examples online.

https://github.com/certbot/certbot/tree/master/certbot-dns-dnsimple

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/812038/375527 If this not answers your question, then you can take a look at the code itself https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/certbot-dns-dnsimple/certbot_dns_dnsimple/dns_dnsimple.py

Comment: Instead of a plugin you can look into the manual configuration as suggested by certbot https://certbot-dns-dnsimple.readthedocs.io/en/stable/